# WCF Service through sockets

Tags: wcf, sockets, service

I have developed a WCF service. Now I want my clients can access to it using sockets. I implemented a TCPListener system on my WCF service, but when I try to instantiate my TCPListener object in a separate thread, I get the following error: **An attempt was made to access a Socket in a way that is forbidden by its access permissions**.

My WCF service is hosted locally.

Someone to help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered the answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461257/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbbiden-by-its-access-permiss Without seing the actual code and the way you are listening, the first guess is that the socket is already used for something else.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't let your service implement a socket, communicating is the task of the Binding. You could implement a custom binding which instantiates a TCP channel, some hints [here](http://winterdom.com/2007/02/writingawcftransportchannelpart2) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729350.aspx). You can also just use the net.tcp Binding, if performance is your goal.

Finally the error you get is pretty clear if you search it on the web: it means you're trying to listen on a port that requires administrative privileges or that is already in use.