# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sockets, tcp

I have a website on HostGator and a dedicated server of my own running SQL Server 2008R2. 
The connection string I use is X.X.X.X,1433 which points to the IP address of my dedicated server.
I have made the firewall settings on my server so that I can use SSMS & log into SQL Server from my home PC.

Having done that, I was under the impression that connecting to SQL from my hostGator hosted-site would work just fine.
I receive the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was
>   made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.)

I have looked up this error and found many explanations, but not one dealing with my circumstances.
My server is running Windows 2008 w/IIS 7.5. I was assured by HostGator tech support that there would be no problems from their end.]]

My firewall allows TCP port 1433, & the UDP port 1434 for the SQL Server Browser service.

Since I have a dedicated server, I have no one to ask this question to from my hosting company.

Comment: I got the "...socket...forbidden..." error trying to start a localhost site via the dotnet run command.  Turns out I just forgot there was already a "Start without debugging" session going from Visual Studio that I'd forgotten about.  Derp.

Comment: For me, I changed the port being used to host the web server in my application. My application was using a custom port # 8000 to host the web sever. I changed it to 8081 and it started to work again. I've no idea what went wrong all of a sudden due to which I had started facing this error.

Comment: So imo better solution to this problem than presented here, see the answer by @Echoldman to [Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0/50070: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65272764/850848#72187332).

Answer (score 74):

I had a similar issue with Docker for Windows and Hyper-V having reserved ports for its own use- in my case, it was port `3001` that couldn't be accessed.

- The port wasn't be used by another process- running `netstat -ano | findstr 3001` in an Administrator Powershell prompt showed nothing.
- However, `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` showed that the port was in one of the exclusion ranges.

I was able to follow the solution described in Docker for Windows issue #3171 ([Unable to bind ports: Docker-for-Windows & Hyper-V excluding but not using important port ranges](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171)):

1. Disable Hyper-V:

   ```
   dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
   ```
2. After the required restarts, reserve the port you want so Hyper-V doesn't reserve it back:

   ```
   netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=3001 numberofports=1
   ```
3. Reenable Hyper-V:

   ```
   dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
   ```

After this, I was able to start my docker container.

Comment: This worked only when my hyper-v was disabled, as soon as I turned on hyper-v again, I started getting the same error.
Running this in admin pwsh worked for me 
```Restart-Service hns -f
```

Comment: [One particular solution](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-750779531) in the linked Github issue worked for me without worrying about specific ports: `net stop winnat`.

Comment: @AbhiAbzs that command worked for me too but I had to run it twice. I had issues with 3 ports, the first run of the command fixed 2 of them and the second run fixed the rest.
I observed that the exclusion ranges changes per restart. 
Before anyone thinks this command doesn't work for them, ensure to run the command below to see the exclusion range after restart.

```netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp```

Answer (score 32):

Just `Restart-Service hns` can change the ports occupied by Hyper-V. It might release the port you need.

Comment: Easy & effective solution for me.

Comment: So simple and effective, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! -- It worked for me but I had to add " -force" to make it work.

Answer (score 20):

Per this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/e0cc1b3e-2c63-451a-abc8-8e1e66a23287/):

the symptom could occur if the replication service tries to use the ports that occupied by others, or by a malfunction NIC. Please try the following steps:

1. Restart the windows firewall service
2. Reboot the problematic machine
3. Restart the “TCP/IP stack”.  Run CMD as administrator, type “netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt” to reset TCP/IP.
4. Try to temporarily disable antivirus.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response @Jason...Found this link: support.microsoft.com/kb/968872?wa=wsignin1.0 and used the accompanying instructions to re-do the firewall settings on my server. Now, thankfully, it's working!

Comment: McAfee antivirus blocks port 25 by default, "to prevent mass mail attacks".

Comment: Bitdefender also blocked the port in question

Comment: @RugerSR9; you are right. I had to add Databasemail.exe (for SQL Server 2016) to the exclude list to get mails to go out. Thank you for posting.

Comment: Thanks mate. For me, running only step no. 3 and restarting my machine worked.

Answer (score 8):

Not surprisingly, this error can arise when another process is listening on the desired port. This happened today when I started an instance of the Apache Web server, listening on its default port (80), having forgotten that I already had IIS 7 running, and listening on that port. This is well explained in [Port 80 is being used by SYSTEM (PID 4), what is that?](http://Port%2080%20is%20being%20used%20by%20SYSTEM%20(PID%204),%20what%20is%20that?) Better yet, that article points to [Stop http.sys from listening on port 80 in Windows](https://www.mikeplate.com/2011/11/06/stop-http-sys-from-listening-on-port-80-in-windows/), which explains a very simple way to resolve it, with just a tad of help from an elevated command prompt and a one-line edit of my **hosts** file.

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 4):

My windows firewall was blocking port 8080 so i changed it to 5000 and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/33859341/446250, having internet connection sharing enabled for my ethernet adapter ended up causing this problem for me. Disabling the sharing fixed the problem

Comment: This also applies if you are using Hyper-v and have the Hyper-V bridge enabled.  Note that a reboot is required after disabling the bridge.

Answer (score 1):

My situation and solution: I had created and enabled a HyperV ethernet adapter. For some reason, my main windows machine was using the "virtual" ethernet adapter instead of the 'hardware' adapter.

I disabled the virtual ethernet and my network settings to change the network public/privacy settings were revealed.

Comment: this solution worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If You need to access SQL server on hostgator remotely using SSMS, you need to white list your IP in hostgator.
Usually it takes 1 hour to open port for the whitelisted IP

Answer (score 0):

For others who get this error but have a slightly different cause, you can do the following to troubleshoot.  Open a text editor by right clicking and choosing Run As Administrator.  Open C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v4\web\pgAdmin4.py and add one line of code without anything else.  The output will be drastically different and helpful.  You can find the error in the system tray > pgAdmin > View Log.

```
import traceback # <--- add this line too.
try:
    app.run(
        host=config.DEFAULT_SERVER,
        port=config.EFFECTIVE_SERVER_PORT,
        use_reloader=(
            (not app.PGADMIN_RUNTIME) and app.debug and
            os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN") is not None
        ),
        threaded=config.THREADED_MODE
    )

except IOError:
    #app.logger.error("Error starting the app server: %s", sys.exc_info())
    app.logger.error("Error starting the app server: %s", traceback.format_exc()) # <--- add this line!
```

Instead of this:

```
ERROR flask.app: Error starting the app server: (<class 'OSError'>, OSError(10013, 'An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions', None, 10013, None),
```

You will get this:

```
2021-03-01 11:38:33,817: ERROR  flask.app:  Error starting the app server: (<class 'OSError'>, OSError(10013, 'An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions', None, 10013, None), <traceback object at 0x00000279EF74A3C0>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/pgAdmin 4/v4/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 210, in main
    app.run(
  File "C:/Program Files/pgAdmin 4/v4/venv/Lib/site-packages\flask\app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:/Program Files/pgAdmin 4/v4/venv/Lib/site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "C:/Program Files/pgAdmin 4/v4/venv/Lib/site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 996, in inner
    srv = make_server(
  File "C:/Program Files/pgAdmin 4/v4/venv/Lib/site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 847, in make_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer(
  File "C:/Program Files/pgAdmin 4/v4/venv/Lib/site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "C:/Program Files/pgAdmin 4/v4/venv/Lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:/Program Files/pgAdmin 4/v4/venv/Lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:/Program Files/pgAdmin 4/v4/venv/Lib\socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Comment: You can manually set the port by going to system tray > PgAdmin > Configure > Runtime tab > Fixed Port Number and Port. Ideally, this port should be set to be within the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port range to avoid a conflict.  Check availability here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve an identical error message on a local Analysis Services instance by turning off loopback address filtering in the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me. Grep couldn't find the culprit listener. Resetting TCP / IP or Firewall didn't do anything either. The following command solved it:

```
net stop http
```