# Socket error using the validate_email 1.1 package

Tags: python, sockets, port, email-validation

I trying to get validate_email package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email) to verify an email for me on a Windows 7/Python 2.7 device.  The following works:

```
>>> validate_email('example@example.com')
True
>>> validate_email('example@example.com',check_mx=True)
True
>>> validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True)
True
```

But when I try a commercial email server example to check if the host has SMPT Server and/or the email really exists, it fails as follows:

```
>>> validate_email('example@gmail.com')
True
>>> validate_email('example@gmail.com',check_mx=True)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\validate_email.py", line 104, in validate_email
    smtp.connect(mx[1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>>> validate_email('example@gmail.com',verify=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\validate_email.py", line 104, in validate_email
    smtp.connect(mx[1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

It appears that I'm trying to access a port that I don't have permission to, but I don't know how to change to a port that would work and has the correct permissions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be a problem with Windows Firewall blocking access to certain ports.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15628078/1308566