# How To Connect to a Socket in C# Like PuTTY?

Tags: c#, sockets

Forgive me, but I am quite a newbie when it comes to this.  I am trying to find a way to connect to a socket in C# similar to what I would be able to do with PuTTY.  For instance, in PuTTy, for my purpose, I would enter the IP and port, select Raw connection type, then open the connection.  I thought the below code would work, but it throws a SocketException saying "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions".

```
class Class_1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        /*
         * Below is not the actual IP and port I am using, of course.
         * It is simply for illustrative purposes.
         */
        socket.Connect(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }), 1);
        Console.WriteLine(socket.Poll(10000000, SelectMode.SelectRead));
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Any help would be most appreciate.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be surprised if there were something on the other end listening at the IP 1.1.1.1.  You'll need to substitute the IP address of a Putty server you have access to.

Comment: Sorry.  To be clear, I am not actually trying to connect to 1.1.1.1:1, I am just using that as a placeholder for the illustrative purpose.

Also, as I do not know how to now edit my post, a bit more info:
The exception occurs in the very first line when creating the new Socket object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619921/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start the program as admin if you are using `SocketType.Raw`