# pdo_sqlsvr SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect remotely to the mssql server by using `pdo sql_srv` but I still get error by fallwoing.**PDOException**:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP
>   Provider: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by
>   its access permissions.

I also enabled port from firewall and Server Configuration TCP enabled.

```
  class Database {

            public $error;
            public $ok;
            public $dead;
            var $query_id; 
            var $LastPDOResult;
            var $La

stPDOResultCursor;
        var $SQLDebug;
        var $sql;
        // Constructor --> Connect
        function __construct($SQLHOST, $SQLPORT, $SQLDB, $SQLUSER, $SQLPWD) {
            try {

                if(PDODRIVER == 3) {
                    $this->db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=".$SQLHOST.";Database=".$SQLDB."; Uid=".$SQLUSER.";Pwd=".$SQLPWD.";");
                } else {
                    if(PDODRIVER == 2) {
                        $pdo_connect = "sqlsrv:Server=".$SQLHOST.",".$SQLPORT.";Database=".$SQLDB."";
                    } else {
                        $pdo_connect = 'dblib:host='.$SQLHOST.':'.$SQLPORT.';dbname='.$SQLDB;
                    }
                    $this->db = new PDO($pdo_connect, $SQLUSER, $SQLPWD);
                }


            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->dead = true;
                $this->error = "PDOException: ".$e->getMessage();

                if(config('ERROR_REPORTING',true)) {
                    die($this->error);
                } else {
                    //die('website offline');
                    die($this->error);
                }
            }

        }
    }

$dB = new Database(DBHOST, DBPORT, DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

Comment: Try steps from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619921/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi