# While sending a email such errors occurs ...not working its live

Tags: php

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013)
>   The following From address failed: info@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected.
>
> ```
>   $mail = new PHPMailer();                    
>     $mail->IsSMTP(); 
>     $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; 
>     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
>     $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";  
>     $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
>     $mail->Port = 587; 
>     $mail->Username = "name@gmail.com"; 
>     $mail->Password = "password";        
>     $mail->From = "info@gmail.com";
>     $mail->FromName = "name.com";
>     $mail->Subject = "Register";
>     $mail->MsgHTML($userMsg);
>
>   $mail->AddAddress("useremail", "username");
>
>   $mail->send();
>     $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619921/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi)

Comment: is this an server issue not any problem in code right mine too is windows server

Comment: Try using port `465` instead.

Comment: not working with port 465

Comment: here is a solution for you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer)

Comment: Here is a [bunch](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+%22email%22+%22error%22) of questions that might help you. Please utilize the advanced search feature before posting a    question here..

Comment: Thats a server code is right. server is not allowing to send emails.