# E NETWORK [thread1] listen(): listen() failed An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: windows, mongodb, sockets, server, listen

I am new to MongoDB. However, after installing it, in my **command prompt**, I typed **md \data\db** where it created a folder as said in my C drive. Now after it, I typed

> "mongod"

to start the mongodb server first.

It showed the following in cmd.

> 2017-10-24T23:08:28.525+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB
>   starting : pid=3 608 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit
>   host=INSPIRION 2017-10-24T23:08:28.527+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   targetMinOS: Windows 7/W indows Server 2008 R2
>   2017-10-24T23:08:28.527+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
>   v3.4.9 2017-10-24T23:08:28.527+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git
>   version: 876ebee8c7d d0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e
>   2017-10-24T23:08:28.528+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL
>   version: OpenSSL
>    1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016 2017-10-24T23:08:28.528+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc 2017-10-24T23:08:28.529+0530 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none 2017-10-24T23:08:28.529+0530 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
>   2017-10-24T23:08:28.529+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod:
>   2008plus-ss l 2017-10-24T23:08:28.530+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>   distarch: x86_64 2017-10-24T23:08:28.530+0530 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64 2017-10-24T23:08:28.531+0530 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp : "127.0.0.1" } }
>   2017-10-24T23:08:28.532+0530 W -        [initandlisten] Detected
>   unclean shutdow n - C:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.
>   2017-10-24T23:08:28.533+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data
>   files in C :\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so
>   setting the active sto rage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
>   2017-10-24T23:08:28.535+0530 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering
>   data from the  last clean checkpoint. 2017-10-24T23:08:28.535+0530 I
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config:
>   create,cache_size=1487M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4)
>   ,config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal
>   ,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,lo
>   g_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0), 2017-10-24T23:08:30.559+0530 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] 2017-10-24T23:08:30.559+0530 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access contr ol is not enabled for the
>   database. 2017-10-24T23:08:30.560+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **
>   Read and wri te access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
>   2017-10-24T23:08:30.560+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   2017-10-24T23:08:30.805+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing
>   full-time d iagnostic data capture with directory
>   'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data' 2017-10-24T23:08:31.087+0530 I FTDC
>   [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data  capture shutdown detected,
>   found interim file, some metrics may have been lost.  OK
>   2017-10-24T23:08:31.249+0530 E NETWORK  [thread1] listen(): listen()
>   failed An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by
>   its access permissions.

And I am wondering about the last line here :

> 2017-10-24T23:08:31.249+0530 E NETWORK  [thread1] listen(): listen()
>   failed An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by
>   its access permissions.

I could not get a correct solution for this error. Can anyone help me in resolving this because only after this, I will be able to start the shell program which shows the following currently.

> C:\Users\DELL>mongo MongoDB shell version v3.4.9 connecting to:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 2017-10-24T23:21:39.937+0530 W NETWORK 
>   [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 :27017 after 5000ms
>   milliseconds, giving up. 2017-10-24T23:21:39.938+0530 E QUERY
>   [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to ser ver 127.0.0.1:27017,
>   connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
>   @(connect):1:6 exception: connect failed

For additional info, am using windows

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619921/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi

Comment: But I also tried netstat -an. That returned all the ip and ports using currently. My port 27017 is not listed there. What does it mean then?