# Possible conflict between Python 3 and Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, package-control

I installed Python 3 two days ago and since then I can't make Sublime Text 3 work properly.

I'm not sure it's because of Python.  Perhaps it has something to do with the `PATH` environment variable that Python overwrote - I can't tell. Or just some conflict between the Python version I installed on my machine and Python that is used with Sublime? One thing I'm sure of is that it's not my internet connection. My firewall rules allow everything for Sublime Text.

Sublime Text shoots this error on startup:

```
Emmet: Loading https://api.github.com/repos/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/contents
emmet.pyv8loader: Unable to download packages list. URL error [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions downloading https://api.github.com/repos/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/contents.
```

I also can't use the Package manager; it says:

```
Package Control

There are no packages available for installation

Please see https://packagecontrol.io/docs/troubleshooting for help
```

Comment: You might have [something else using the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45355519/1270789), like a web server, or do you need to set a proxy server address?

Comment: No, I'm not using any proxy with it. No VPN or something either. I have nodejs installed on the machine, but it's not running - obviously I tried to even reboot the system to clear anything - connections, processes - before trying again.

Comment: Blocked by firewall maybe ?

Comment: Are you running an antivirus program?  Can you try running Sublime Text as an administrator?