# Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0/50070: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: docker, hadoop, port, docker-image

I am trying to start a docker container with the below command.

```
docker run -it -p 50070:50070 -p 8088:8088 -p 8080:8080 suhothayan/hadoop-spark-pig-hive:2.9.2 bash
```

It ended up with the following error.

> docker: error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0/50070: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

As I understand, the error has occurred as the port 50070 is used by another process. I've tried to identify the process in order to kill that with the below command in the command prompt, but it does not give an output nor an error.

```
netstat -ano | findstr :50080
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619921/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As per Docker issue for windows https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171 :

You might have that port in any of the excluded port ranges of command `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

You can use solution mentioned in the above ticket.

1. Disable hyper-v (which will required a couple of restarts)

   `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`
2. After finishing all the required restarts, reserve the port you want so hyper-v doesn't reserve it back

   `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=50070 numberofports=1`
3. Re-Enable hyper-V (which will require a couple of restart)

   `dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All`

Answer (score 308):

[This](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-739740248) solution helped me (run as administrator your terminal):

```
net stop winnat
docker start container_name
net start winnat
```

Comment: This doesn't explain _why_ things fail.

Comment: Thanks it helped me. I was facing the same error, I ran the first command (net stop winnat) in administrator mode of windows powershell then, I ran (docker-compose up --build -d) and at the end I ran the last command(net start winnat).

Comment: Hit this problem for the first time (despite having used this container many times) today on my Windows 11 machine (23H2, 22631.2199). This fix worked, thank you.

Answer (score 104):

I did this to stop tcp processes =>

- net stop winnat
- net start winnat

In this way, the busy port operation is terminated.

This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! This one worked for me in Windows 10.

Comment: thanks! worked for me too, not sure why though

Answer (score 12):

Restarting `winnat` is not a good idea. The root cause is that some ports of Windows are dynamically reserved, even though they are not occupied. This command can be used to solve.

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
netsh int ipv6 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
```

This article explains it in detail, and I recommend taking a look at it:
[Completely solve the problem of docker containers running on Windows 10 due to port binding](https://medium.com/@sevenall/completely-solve-the-problem-of-docker-containers-not-starting-or-running-on-windows-10-due-to-port-57f16ed6143)

Comment: The link really helped explain and seems like the most appropriate way to solve the problem. Disabling Hyper-V seems like overkill and extra restarts.

Answer (score 4):

I faced with this situation when my VPN connection is active.
you can temporarily disconnect your VPN connection, after that start your `docker container`, and go back and connect to your VPN again

Answer (score 4):

1. run `net stop winnat`
2. If you use docker desktop, just run the container. Otherwise run this command in command prompt: `docker start <container_name>`
3. run `net start winnat`

Answer (score 2):

On my local machine had similar issue with Docker Desktop and integration enabled with Debian/Ubuntu set as default distro (WSL2 as standard to all). How I solved:

- Docker settings disabled "Start Docker Desktop when you log in"
- Restarting Windows
- First starting Debian/Ubuntu
- Then start Docker Desktop

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting "Host Network Service"

Answer (score 2):

This is often caused by the Windows NAT Driver (winnat), stopping and restarting that service may resolve the issue.

open shell as administrator, and types those commands:

1. net stop winnat.
2. docker start ...
3. net start winnat

Comment: This answer had already been provided by Cepr0 last year.

Comment: I like both answers, the main thing is that you need to restart the winnat service, and after that it will work like it's intended to.

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable Windows IIS:

- Call Control Panel > Programs and Features Click Turn Windows
  features on or off Scroll down to Internet Information Services

[image]

- Click on the square next to Internet Information Services so it becomes empty

[image]

- Click OK and reboot if required.

See https://superuser.com/questions/1377068/how-do-i-disable-the-iis-server-on-windows-10-and-free-up-port-80

Also, I had to enable `Hyper-V` along with `Virtual Machine Platform` and `Windows Hypervisor Platform`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your docker-compose.yaml file.
2. Locate the service definition where the port conflict is happening.
3. In that service, leave the HOST_PORT empty. This will allow Docker to dynamically generate a port every time your container starts.

For instance,

```
ports:
  -5672:5672
  -15672:15672
```

Do it:

```
ports:
  - :5672
  - :15672
```

You can check the dynamically assigned port through Docker Desktop or by running docker-compose ps.

Answer (score 0):

```
***net stop winnat
docker start container_name
net start winnat***
```

writing this in cmd worked well for me, thank you so much commentators for the solution.