# Windows 10, Docker problem with Port 80, Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80:

Tags: docker, windows-10, port, docker-desktop

I was trying to run docker app...

```
λ docker run -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 --name billingapp sotobotero/udemy-devops:0.0.1
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

I was trying to apply this answer...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65274083/811293

```
λ netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=80 numberofports=1
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I was trying with https://stackoverflow.com/a/66198584/811293

```
D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d
λ docker container rm billingapp
billingapp

D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d
λ net stop winnat
The Windows NAT Driver service is not started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.


D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d
λ docker run -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 --name billingapp sotobotero/udemy-devops:0.0.1
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d
λ
```

Checking with Resource Monitor...
[image]

Checking with `netstat`

```
D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d
λ netstat -aon | find /i "listening"  | findStr ":80"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:808            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4140
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:808               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4140

D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d
λ
```

Using `tasklist`

```
D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d
λ tasklist /FI "PID eq 4"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System                           4 Services                   0        144 K

D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d
λ
```

VERSION Docker Desktop:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | select DisplayName,DisplayVersion | where {$_.DisplayName -like "Docker*"}

DisplayName    DisplayVersion
-----------    --------------
Docker Desktop 2.5.0.0


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

In other side:

```
D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d                             
λ docker --version                                             
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d                      
                                                               
D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d                             
λ docker version                                               
Client: Docker Engine - Community                              
 Cloud integration: 1.0.1                                      
 Version:           19.03.13                                   
 API version:       1.40                                       
 Go version:        go1.13.15                                  
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d                                 
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:00:27 2020                   
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64                              
 Experimental:      false                                      
                                                               
Server: Docker Engine - Community                              
 Engine:                                                       
  Version:          19.03.13                                   
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)                
  Go version:       go1.13.15                                  
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d                                 
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:07:04 2020                   
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64                                
  Experimental:     false                                      
 containerd:                                                   
  Version:          v1.3.7                                     
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175   
 runc:                                                         
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10                                 
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd   
 docker-init:                                                  
  Version:          0.18.0                                     
  GitCommit:        fec3683                                    
                                                               
D:\Programs\cmder\config\profile.d
```

**What other solution I need try to apply?**

Comment: Try... this question.... https://stackoverflow.com/q/1430141/811293

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run docker on windows 10 - Ports are not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874912/cant-run-docker-on-windows-10-ports-are-not-available)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, got rid of it with this command

```
NET stop HTTP
```

it stopped the print queue service ("Druckwarteschlange" in German).

Bad side effect, you can't use your printer anymore..