# Error when running server using the same port?

Tags: python, sockets

In the code;

```
import socket
HOST = ''   #another short form for INADDDR_ANY, all available interfaces
PORT = 50010 #arbitrary non-priviledged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
```

I am getting an error

```
socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forb
idden by its access permissions
```

The error points to s.bind(). Any clues as to why this is happening?
Basically, I don't want to change the port number each time I make some changes to server code.

Comment: Are you closing down the sockets correctly when exiting your program? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461257/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbbiden-by-its-access-permiss

Comment: Yes I have added close(), but it throws an error much earlier

Comment: What platform windows or linux?

Comment: I am using windows 7 and python 2.7

Comment: Possibly a UAC thing?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb