# How to drop into a debugger in a Jasmine test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, node-inspector

I'm improving my JavaScript by doing exercises on Exercism.io; I'm currently working on http://exercism.io/exercises/javascript/leap/readme.

So far, I've written a `leap.js` like so:

```
var Year = function (year) {};

Year.prototype.isLeap = function () {
    return (this.year % 4 === 0 && this.year % 100 !== 0) || this.year % 400 === 0
};

module.exports = Year;
```

The Jasmine test, `leap.spec.js`, is

```
var Year = require('./leap');

describe('Leap year', function () {
  it('is not very common', function () {
    var year = new Year(2015);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(false);
  });

  it('is introduced every 4 years to adjust about a day', function () {
    var year = new Year(2016);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('is skipped every 100 years to remove an extra day', function () {
    var year = new Year(1900);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(false);
  });

  it('is reintroduced every 400 years to adjust another day', function () {
    var year = new Year(2000);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(true);
  });
```

However, some tests are still failing:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:leap kurtpeek$ jasmine leap.spec.js
Started
.F.F

Failures:
1) Leap year is introduced every 4 years to adjust about a day
  Message:
    Expected false to be true.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected false to be true.
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/kurtpeek/exercism/javascript/leap/leap.spec.js:11:27)

2) Leap year is reintroduced every 400 years to adjust another day
  Message:
    Expected false to be true.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected false to be true.
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/kurtpeek/exercism/javascript/leap/leap.spec.js:21:27)

Ran 4 of 8 specs
4 specs, 2 failures
Finished in 0.009 seconds
```

Strangely, if I copy what is `return`ed to the Node REPL with `this.year` replaced by `2016`, I get `true` as expected:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:leap kurtpeek$ node
> (2016 % 4 === 0 && 2016 % 100 !== 0) || 2016 % 400 === 0
true
```

What I suspect is happening is that `this.year` is not the number `2016`, but the instance `year` of `Year` that was instantiated previously, so that the modulo expression doesn't make sense.

To confirm this, however, I would like to inspect the variables in the scope of the `isLeap` function. After some Googling I've tried installing [`jasmine-debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-debug) and [`jasmine-node-debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-node-debug), but when I try to run either one of them (after inserting a `debugger;` statement before the `return` statement) I get the following error:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:leap kurtpeek$ jasmine-node-debug
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '_debugger'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node-debug/node_modules/node-inspector/lib/debugger.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
```

From what I've read at https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4307, this error has to do with the Node.js team migrating users to the new `inspect` API - basically, these packages are outdated.

Is there any other way to enter the debugger through a Jasmine test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to start the debugger by running `node --inspect-brk` with the `jasmine.js` file called by Jasmine's CLI:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:bin kurtpeek$ node --inspect-brk /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js ~/exercism/javascript/leap/leap.spec.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/03d10b73-1d60-4db3-be79-850f7ee4d0d6
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Started
```

Then, upon navigating to `chrome://inspect` in the Chrome browser and hitting 'continue', I was able to determine that `this.year` is indeed `undefined`:

[image]

I then fixed the test by defining `this.year`:

```
var Year = function (year) {
    this.year = year;
};

Year.prototype.isLeap = function () {
    return (this.year % 4 === 0 && this.year % 100 !== 0) || this.year % 400 === 0
};

module.exports = Year;
```

Now the tests pass:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:bin kurtpeek$ jasmine ~/exercism/javascript/leap/leap.spec.js
Started
....


Ran 4 of 8 specs
4 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.009 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting **this.year** anywhere.

In the function **isLeap()**, this.year is *undefined* hence specs for falsy are passed.

> You can console.log() inside your spec and see its value any time. It will be printed to the terminal as well as the browser instance.
>   You may try **dump()** as well.

Try this:

```
var Year = function (year) {
    this.year = year;
};
```

You may also confirm what data type **this.year** is holding, using

```
expect(this.year).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
```

Comment: My question wasn't so much about how to solve this problem rather than how to drop into the debugger so that I can have all the variables at my fingertips and more quickly solve these problems in the future.

Comment: Bit off topic don't ya thing?