# Why Can't I access FTP site programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm trying to write a program that will automatically download the latest client files from from their FTP site.  I can successfully access the site using an FTP client, but when I try to do so programmatically, I run into errors.  I've tried multiple FTP clients and I can't get any of them to work.

For example, I use WinSCP to access the site, and it has this handy feature where it generates the code necessary to connect to the current site.  Here's an example:

```
// Set up session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.site.com",
    PortNumber = 21,
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Your code
}
```

I can copy that generated code verbatim, put it into a c# program, and I get the error

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions x.x.x.x:21

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or does the client have something configured on their FTP site that prevents what I'm trying to do?

---

After something changed on my end, I don't know exactly what, the errors went away and I can now successfully access the FTP site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [an attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbbiden by it's access permissions. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461257/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbbiden-by-its-access-permiss)

Comment: For what its worth; I would try the built in classes or FluentFTP. I've never heard of or tried WinSCP

Comment: WinSCP allows access to SFTP sites. That's the only reason I can see for using it with C#.

Comment: I actually tried FluentFTP first, but was getting the same error.  The reason I chose WinSCP as an example was to show that my code wasn't the problem.

Comment: *"I can successfully access the site using an FTP client"* - Are you running the FTP client on **same** machine as your code? Show us a verbose log file of both the FTP client and your code. Once you have the WinSCP code, the best is if you show us WinSCP code log file (`Session.SessionLogPath`) and a corresponding WinSCP GUI log file.

Comment: Welp, I don't know what changed, but now it's working and I didn't do anything differently.  The only things that were different were I tried (unsuccessfully) to run the program with elevated privileges and there was an update pushed by IT.  This is super frustrating.  So, do I close this question or do I update it and leave it open?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with **WebClient** of [System.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@somedomain.com", "my-pwd");
    client.DownloadFile("ftp://11.22.33.44/myfile.txt", @"C:\myfile.txt");
}
```

Make sure your app has access to the output location (`@"C:\myfile.txt"` in my example).

Comment: I've tried that and get `Unable to connect to the remote server`.  I get similar errors when I try to use the related FtpWebRequest.

Comment: @greenjaed - Does your IDE offer any more details on that exception?

Comment: The only thing in the inner exception is `'($exception).Response.ContentType' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'`

Answer (score 0):

You could always try the FtpWebRequest class from System.Net:

```
string url = "11.22.33.44";
string user = "username@somedomain.com";
string pwd = "my-pwd";
string fileName = @"C:\myfile.txt";

var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("ftp://{0}/{1}", url, filename));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);

using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var targetStream = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        if (responseStream != null)
            responseStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
```

Comment: As I've mentioned in the other answer, I've tried this approach and get the exception `Unable to connect to the remote server`

Comment: Ahh didn't catch that sorry.