# Insufficient port permissions

Tags: c#, tcp, websocket, port, netstat

I am trying to create a Websocket Server on my local machine by doing:

```
WebSocketServer server = new WebSocketServer("ws://127.0.0.1:5040");
```

but I am getting the error:

`An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

even though `netstat -an` shows that the port `5040` is in the `LISTENING` state.
I have tried running Visual Studio in admin mode, disabled my firewalls etc. but I keep getting the error. Am I supposed to use a port that does not appear when running `netstat -an`? If not, how do I fix the above error?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461257/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbbiden-by-its-access-permissi/10461978#10461978

Comment: My situation doesn’t seem to have been solved by this answers

Comment: ok, it was worth a try...

Comment: You say the port is listet as `LISTENING`? In that case you can run `netstat -o` to find out which process is using the port as described in the proposed duplicate question's answer. If the port is already in use by another process, you can't use it and need to use another port.

Comment: The port does not appear when running `netstat -o`

Comment: You want `netstat -ano`. What operating system are you on? Also, anti-viruses can prevent certain ports from being listened on.

Comment: Windows 10 and I have no 3rd party anti virus

Comment: If you already have 5040 in `LISTENING` state from `netstat -an`, it's already in use by something. You have to pick another port or kill the service that's using it (`-ano` will give you the PID in the last column). I recall one of the Windows services using 5040.

Comment: I understand now, so how do I choose an appropriate port that isn’t currently occupied?

Comment: Pick a random port (ideally with five digits) and hope that nothing else is using it