# Connecting to Websocket on shared hosting when port is blocked

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, binance, websocket4net

I built a program in c# (asp.net) that connects to wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws using WebSocket4Net, and gets ticker data which is public.

My application runs fine on localhost, but on my hosting provider I get an error `"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"` which is an issue of blocked port if I understand correctly.

My hosting provider allows me to enable specific ports for specific ip addresses, but in this case I don't have the ip address for the remote host wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws

Is there a way to find out the ip address of the remote host when connection is open or when a message is received?

My code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using WebSocket4Net;
public static class BinanceWShandler
{
    static WebSocket ws;
    internal static bool isOpen { get; private set; }

    public static void Start()
    {

        ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws");
        ws.Opened += Ws_Opened;
        ws.Closed += Ws_Closed;
        ws.Error += Ws_Error;
        ws.MessageReceived += Ws_MessageReceived;
        ws.EnableAutoSendPing = true;
        ws.Open();
    }

    private static void Ws_Error(object sender, SuperSocket.ClientEngine.ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private static void Ws_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private static void Ws_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Request_Individual_Ticker obj = new Request_Individual_Ticker();
        obj.method = "SUBSCRIBE";
        List<string> pars = new List<string>();
        pars.Add("!bookTicker");
        obj.@params = pars;
        obj.id = 1;
        string JSONstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        ws.Send(JSONstring);
        isOpen = true;
    }

    private static void Ws_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SignalRChat.Hubs.ChatHub.instance.SendBinanceWS(e.Message);
    }

    public class Request_Individual_Ticker
    {
        public string method { get; set; }
        public List<string> @params { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you have check this ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461257/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbbiden-by-its-access-permissi

Comment: Yes I have, that doesn't seem to be the problem though. 
I was able to find one of their ip addresses and whitelisted it, now I can receive messages occasionally depending on which ip address I connect to.
Is there a way to figure out the ip address when I run it in debug mode? I can open different connections and collect all the ip address they use that way.