# why my uvicorn server suddenly show error : [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

1. I have been studying a FastAPI framework and starting five to 6 days were seem less as in everything was working fine w.r.t. the documentation

2.but today when I start my app server my command "uvicorn main:app --reload" it shoed the error:
**[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**

3. most frustrating thing is that yesterday it was working fine before i go to bed, but today morning i got this error(i literally changed nothing but it shows error)

Comment: You probably already have the socket in use by a different process - i.e. your previous instance of uvicorn / python script is still running. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461257/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.