# Exception when sending email in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to test out sending an email in my asp.net mvc application but I keep getting the exception below thrown:

**"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ipaddress:587"**

Any ideas what it could be? I have turned off windows firewall and I still get the exception. I have included the using System.Net.Mail; statement and my code is below:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@mydomain.com", "mypassword");

mail.From = new MailAddress("info@mydomain.com");
mail.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Testing application";
mail.Body = "Testing the application email";   
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I've used gmail before to send and thinking I added `SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;` just before `.Send`. Trying to find my code now...

Comment: I tried the SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true; earlier and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code that working. Have two extra setting compare it with yours, maybe this is the issue.

```
MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage("a@gmail.com", "b@mail.me", "subject", "message body");
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("a@gmail.com", "a");
try
{
   smtp.Send(msgMail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: Not working with both extra settings or just adding one of them. Same error.

Comment: @General_9 this is working for sure. The next think is that maybe your server block this port ?

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange yes firewall settings, or work on a virtual pc and this port is mix up.

Comment: @General_9 check the firewall settings. Look similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799651/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi

Comment: I am working on my local pc and trying to run this code off my localhost. I have turned off windows firewall already. Do you mean my server blocking it as in IIS?

Comment: @General_9 If its on your local computer then your router (the connection with the internet) may cut it off.

Comment: @General_9 make a ping to `smtp.gmail.com` to see if you get the correct ip. (from a dos windows)

Comment: ping to smtp.gmail.com works correctly..I deployed my code to my web host server and it still crashes. It just doesn't make sense.