# WCF: The specified registry key does not exist in base.Channel call

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, registry

I am getting an error: "The specified registry key does not exist" when the following WCF code is being executed:

```
return base.Channel.GetRateSheet(request);
```

This is the rest of the method in which this is used:

```
public GetRateSheetResponse GetRateSheet(GetRateSheetRequest request)
{
    return base.Channel.GetRateSheet(request);
}
```

The config for this endpoint is:

```
<endpoint address="http://*********/*******/Service.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IBusinessService"
          name="Endpoint_RateSheetService"
          contract="*********.RateSheetService" />
```

This code used to work for many weeks, and this morning is started throwing this error.

There is no inner exception and the only stack trace I get is:

```
at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
```

I did all the common tire-kicking: restarted VS, rebooted machine, got latest version of the source code.

Running XP 32 bit.

[EDIT:] When I go to the bin folder of the solution and run the executable direcly, it works - no error. The error only occurs when running from Visual Studio

Comment: When you say you got latest version are you talking about .NET 4.5?

Comment: no, version of the source code from source control. Thanks.

Comment: Any recent OS or VS updates?

Comment: it looks like there was a n OS update over the weekend - the guy next to me said his PC rebooted. OS update is quite plausable.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Seems people have faced [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141434/httpclient-request-throws-ioexception) after installing a security patch for the .NET Framework: [MS12-074: Vulnerabilities in .NET Framework could allow remote code execution: November 13, 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2745030)

You can [ask microsoft to fix it here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773666/webrequest-create-eats-an-ioexception-on-the-first-call#details)

Workaround - Add the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"LegacyWPADSupport"=dword:00000000
```

For 64 bit machines

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"LegacyWPADSupport"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Yes, but only if it arose after installing that particular security patch.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue while debugging something today. The exception goes away if you check the "Just my code" option in the debugging settings inside VS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to --> Debug-->Exceptions and uncheck "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

This should reslove issue.