# Application Insights not working - socket exception

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-application-insights

I have added Application Insights inside my windows store application and in output i have lot of lines that exception was rised.

I have ApplicationInsight message:

```
Application Insights Telemetry: {"ver":1,"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PageView",.............}
```

Exceptions like:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.InternalException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.InternalException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.winmd
A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.InternalException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.InternalException' occurred in System.dll
```

Exception message is:

```
Message "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 23.101.68.210:443"
```

I really do not know what causing this exception. I tried turn off firewall but with no success. I try develop application in VS 2013 with update 4 and machine is with Windows 2012 R2

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799651/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is on a windows store app, have you turned on the capabilities in the manifest that allow the application to make outbound network requests?

see related: 
[An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799651/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi)

I had the team that owns the instructions update their page here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-monitor-usage-crashes/, so that if you're following those instructions, it calls out specifically to check this setting.  (They investigated, and it seems that windows phone silverlight is the only template that has this setting off by default now, all the current templates have network access on by default?)

Comment: OMG ...it was so easy, but nowhere point to check this...I do not have lot of exp with developing winRT apps so than you .You saved me lot of hoursof investigation.
I do not know if i won but at least i do not have exceptions messages in my VS output window.

Comment: i'll send a note to the team that owns the phone/store sdk to make sure they also put this in their documentation.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it. Maybe it helps someone else too.