# Windows Stores App 407 proxy error connecting to asmx service

Tags: .net, authentication, proxy, windows-store-apps, asmx

My windows stores app receives a 407 error connecting to my asmx web service. I can browse to the webservice via url fine and invoke it in IE. The webservice works when called from a separate project (signalr hub which is hosted on same iis).

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (407) Proxy
>   Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to
>   fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  ).

- The web service reference was created in visual studio by clicking on the references and adding a service reference, I am using the 'serviceReference.SoapClient' way of connecting. This works when not behind a proxy.
- I am running the windows service from the windows 8 emulator built into visual studio. This is on the same machine that has the web service running in IIS.
- I have turned on 'Enterprise Authentication' in the app manifest settings.
- I have added the following to the .asmx web.config.

  ```
  <system.net>
      <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
  ```
- I have tried explicitly setting the credentials but it doesn't appear to make a difference:

  ```
  proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "MYDOMAIN";
  proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "user";
  proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";
  ```
- I have only started getting this issue while on a new network trying to setup the app. It worked ok at home - 'worked on my pc' ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this dilemma by declaring the binding as per the following link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/12/21/help-me-how-do-i-connect-to-an-asmx-web-service.aspx

I also turned on 'Private Networks (Client and Server)' as per [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623477/1497838).

Example of my syntax to help anyone else having this issue:

```
    System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
    System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost/WebService/myFileName.asmx"));
    MyService.MyServiceSoapClient client = new MyService.MyServiceSoapClient(binding, address);
    MyService.MyMethodResponse response = await client.MyMethodAsync(null);
    var result = response.Body.MyMethodResult;
```