# Console Application works when run through visual studio but not when running created .exe

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm-online

I am creating a console application to run in task scheduler. When i am running it through visual studio it works fine, it retrieves data and can output in file or to console.
However, when i am running the exe file it fails. i get the error:

```
  System.InvalidOperationException: metadata contains reference which cannot be resolved <url>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=71. --->
  System.Net.WebException: unable to connect to remote server --->
  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. <ip>:443 etc.
```

This is a solution that is trying to connect to **Crm**.
Does anybody know why it is working just as intended from **VS**, but fails when you just run **.exe** file?
It doesn't matter if i run Vs and step through code or just run it.

Comment: Are you running in Task Scheduler as a specific user with the required permissions?  I suspect not.  So perhaps that is the answer.

Comment: What's the credential to run this tool in task scheduler?

Comment: I just run the .exe file at as test, i have tried running it as admin.
doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you check the URL in the connection string in the .config file? Can you copy/paste it to a browser on the machine running the .exe and get a valid response?

Comment: Hi @Nicknow
yes, im running it from my own machine. i can get into the environment fine through a browser, it works when i run the code through Visual Studio. but the **.exe** file that Visual studio builds has problems.
i dont move the **.exe** file or anything, i just run it directly from the debug folder where it is built.
I suspect that something is missing from the build. It has been devided over several projects in the same solution.

edit: i have also tried changing the adress to containing the Crm company name from dev. ressources. (didn't work either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out was the problem was.
AV/firewall program was blocking.

Program running on your own computer gives various trust levels to programs. Visual studio is running high enough trust that it is allowed access through port 443.
However, .exe files created through Visual Studio doesn't not. Even when running them as admin.

This post is what gave me the answer:
[An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799651/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi)

Thank you very much to rouen for encountering this problem and solving it, before i got into this mess :)