# Issue with SSH.NET UWP

Tags: ssh, ssh.net

I am having issues using SSh.net in a UWP App. This app will run on Win10.
I get the following error:
`An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`. I have looked online and there is no one actually dealing with this.The exact same code works in a standard Desktop App (WPF)

The key is the key string and I had to replace \r with \n because the PrivateKeyFile creation gave an error message and I tracked this down to carriage return placed instead of new line (by the textbox).

```
key = key.Replace("\r", "\n");
PrivateKeyFile(stringToStream(key));
client = new SshClient(ip, port, username, pkf);
if (!client.IsConnected)
{
    try
    {
        client.Connect();
        connected = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exception = ex.Message.ToString();
        connected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us exception callstack and exception type. + Can you connect to the same IP and port using any standalone SSH/SFTP client running on the same machine as your app? Show us its log file.

Comment: I am able to connect usign the exact code but in a standard desktop (WPF) App

Comment: That information should be in the question. Edit it in, please. + Does your UWP app have network permissions?

Comment: Does Your UWP have network permisions? ... I am running it in debug mode and I am not sure how to do that. I have tried giving Visual studio network permission:

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by exception callstack, but, here is exception stacktrace:
       `at Renci.SshNet.Abstractions.SocketAbstraction.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint, TimeSpan connectTimeout)
       at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketConnect(String host, Int32 port)
       at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
       at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
       at iMuneFront.SSHConnect.Connect(String ip, Int32 port, String username, String keyToConnect)`

And:
`NativeErrorCode 10013`
`SocketErrorCode Access Denied`
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have also added this to the SSH.Net Git, [here](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/367) but no response yet. I am having to change to a standard desktop app (thanks to MVVM) untill I am able to resolve this. Thanks a lot for your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this issue - Look here: [An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799651/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi)

Go down to the following line: 
If you're getting the same error in Windows 8 development, it could be that you haven't enabled access over Private Networks in your `Package.appxmanifest` file:

Select the Private Networks (Client & Server) option as shown on the image.

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VK0M.png)

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)