# "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" error get in elastic search nest c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core

i am new in elastic search. i have created sample project to index data into elastic cloud.and trying to retrive this using my c# code. in my local pc my elastic search api working fine but at the time of hosting it give me "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" error.

how to resolve this error?

My sample code into c#

```
    var uri = new Uri("https://elastic:passowrd@cloud url");
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri).DisableDirectStreaming();
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var response1 = client.ClusterHealth();

    _logger.Error("debug info");
    if (response1.DebugInformation != null)
        _logger.Error(response1.DebugInformation    );
```

Full error message display as below:-

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on GET: /_cluster/health
# Audit trail of this API call:
- [1] BadRequest: Node: https://elastic:pt8wcFiAaGdjrz1sJKSI5FfW@4b9793e5c28e4c42ba30026f534b8593.europe-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/ Took: 00:00:00.0553689
# OriginalException: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
# Request:
<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
# Response:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799651/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi)

Comment: i have asked question related to elastic search and your provided link is related to facebook sdk issue so this question is differ from your link.

Comment: It's a permissions problem. Nothing to do with ES IMHO.

Comment: i already know the permision issue @isalgureiro but question is how to solve this ? i already try many think but i can't find any think related to permision into es

Comment: i got the solution. solution is need to run elastic code into https website. i means your testing site must having https or enable ssl

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error. This error is caused because the hosting server you should allow inbound for port 9200-9300. The error specifies that the attempt was made to access an port where permission is not granted

Comment: i got the solution. solution is need to run elastic code into https website. i means your testing site must having https or enable ssl