# .Net core service call throws SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webrequest

I am wrtting a .net core service which fetches some data by calling a api deployed on a docker server.

```
        string url = serviceURL;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = 0;

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
            //logic to access data;
            }
        }
```

I get exception @ **using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())**

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.)'

**Inner Ex** HttpRequestException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

**Inner Ex** SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

The same API on docker server is also been called from a windows based application written in .net framework 4.5 and it works fine there and returns the expected result.

What additional proxy setting is required for .net core application to make a web request?

Comment: Have you checked firewall/av? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799651/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi

Comment: Also, when you say ‘service’, are you talking about a Windows service?

Comment: .net core application